# Get output from running Process

Tags: c#

I'm using C#.

I have C# console applicaiton that I want to get the output from another C# application.

I'm get my process as follow:

```
Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessByName("MyConsoleApp");
```

How can I get the output?

I can't run the application from my another C# application, I'm only can get the process by name.

What I'm trying:

```
proc[0].StartInto.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc[0].StandardOutput.ReadLine();//Throw an exception
```

And I'm got an exception:

> standard out has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet

So How can I read the output without to run the process?

Comment: That is not possible, the OS walls off the console to prevent other processes from stealing secrets.  Only way to do this is to start the process yourself, then you can redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect standard output, process needs to be run by your program, otherwise OS won't let you do it [security measure, you wouldn't want random programs to access your password store or browser when you are logging in to your bank account, would you?], in such case, you first need to set `UseShellExecute` to `false`.

So like this:

```
proc[0].StartInto.UseShellExecute = false;
proc[0].StartInto.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc[0].StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

But if you really are unable to run process from your program, you need to set up other way for them to communicate, be it a temporary file somewhere on disk, pipe, Azure Service Bus, there are many ways, but you cannot make one process just find other process and read it's output.

Comment: I'm trying your solution but still same exception

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough at first. I've expanded my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the standard output of any random process on Windows unless you use the [Win32 debugging APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/debugging-functions).

The only way to do this is to create the process yourself.